# Use a variable in xml-File

Tags: xml, android-studio, variables, android-animation

I have made an animation in android studio. It looks like this:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-120%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="100" />
</set>
```

Now I don't want numbers in there. For example for the duration I want to refere to a variable. I have tried to create a variable in strings.xml and in dimens.xml and the use these like so:

```
android:duration="@dimen/varname"
```

But sadly this does give me an error.
Does anyone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `android:duration` element is an int value so you should be able to easily set it by doing the below:

Step 1) In a xml values file add

```
<integer name="varname">100</integer>
```

Step 2) For the `android:duration` element just do

```
android:duration="@integer/varname"
```

I'd personally consider having an integers.xml file just like you have a strings.xml file but that's me.